# Meteor.user is null after (apparently) successful login

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, google-oauth

I have a simple Meteor js app that allows you to create a user account and log in, or to log in with your existing Google account via oauth (thanks to the `accounts-google` package).

When using the app, I enter my username and password, everything works fine.  However, when I click "Sign in with Google", the google oauth pop-up asks me to select which google account I want to use for this login.  I select the account, the pop up waits a second, closes, and then nothing happens.  No pop-ups being blocked, no "failed login" messages.  It's as if nothing happened at all.

I'm certain that the user is never being defined when I use oauth login because `Meteor.user()` gives me `null` in the JS console.

What could be going on here?  Or how would I debug this?  Suggestions appreciated.

p.s. If any additional information is needed, I can ammend.

Comment: Adding your oauth setup code is always helpful, and be aware that proper configuration must be done in the Google Developers Console too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably messed up oauth configuration either on the Meteor side or Google Developers Console side, so here is a quick recap.

Google Developers Console :

Under APIs & auth > Credentials, create a new Client ID in the OAuth section.

Choose Web Application and specify both correct redirect URIs and JavaScript origins :

REDIRECT URIS

```
http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close
http://your-production-domain.com/_oauth/google?close
```

JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS

```
http://localhost:3000
http://your-production-domain.com
```

Meteor configuration :

Be sure to add these packages :

```
meteor add accounts-google
meteor add service-configuration
```

In server/config.js, add these lines from http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "google"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "google",
  clientId: "????????????????.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  secret: "????????????????"
});
```

The clientId and secret fields should be set to those in the Google Developers Console.

Then call `Meteor.loginWithGoogle()` in the click handler of your login form and it should work as expected.

Comment: It appears to be working now, but I'm not sure why.  Either way, this is better information than the official docs.  Thank you.

Comment: If I'm developing on a remote computer with a public URL, is there a way to change the dev callback URLs to not be localhost? I know it's an old thread, but not finding this answer anywhere on searches.