# Why aren't my configurations for Meteor accounts-google package working any more?

Tags: meteor, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth

I am **NOT** new to configuring the `meteor add service-configuration` specifically the accounts google package, in fact I have done so in several of my projects. It's always been as easy as following the instructions in the popup window (as seen in the image below) to configuring the package, and it has **ALWAYS** worked perfectly.

[image: image illustrating how Id configure the google package into my project]

Ever since Google added the extra field to fill in under **OAuth Consent Screen** tab as seen in the image below

[image: image illustrating googles new security form that's causing me issues]

...I've started getting error messages with my google accounts configurations.

I **do** correctly fill in the **Authorized domains** section, ensuring that the details match the address given in the **Authorized JavaScript origins**  and the **Authorized redirect URIs**, naturally leaving out the **https://www.** section... nevertheless, while signing in via google. I keep getting the below error message:

[image: the error message I get during google signing in]

Can someone kindly explain what is going on here and how I can resolve this?

I found this article [a NOT so clear solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172628/meteor-js-accounts-google-package-not-working-for-me) and tried to follow the instructions but, perhaps the instructions aren't that clear, or are outdated.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: @FullStack Would you perhaps know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @saimeunt Would you perhaps know how to resolve this issue? Desperate here!